# Using Launchd to run MAMP database backup every 2 minutes

Tags: launchd

- I am trying to create a plist file that is run by launchd.
- I want it to run every 2 minutes (for now) and it should execute a mysqldump backup.
- It is used to back up all my local MAMP databases.
- The script itself:

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root -proot --host=localhost --all-databases > ~/Dropbox/Development/Shared\ DBs/BACKUPS/all_databases_-'date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S"'.sql`

works without issue when entered in to the terminal.

- I need to automate this backup, so wrote the following plist file, and put it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.localhost.cron.plist`
- Then ran `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.localhost.cron.plist`, but it isn't triggering every 2 minutes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.localhost.cron.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root -proot --host=localhost --all-databases > ~/Dropbox/Development/Shared\ DBs/BACKUPS/all_databases_-`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S"`.sql</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>120</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Notes

I'm using OS X Mavericks and the latest MAMP.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit

The chosen answer below answers my question well, but I found what I think is a better approach (choice is yours). It is available here: [Send Stderr to dev/null but if no error occurs, continue on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332276/send-stderr-to-dev-null-but-if-no-error-occurs-continue-on/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProgramArgument` value is not correct. You are supposed to provide an extra string for every argument. This should work better:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump</string>
    <string>--opt</string>
    <string>-u</string>
    <string>root</string>
    <string>-proot</string>
    <string>--host=localhost</string>
    <string>--all-databases</string>
</array>
```

Output redirection is done with the key `StandardOutPath`, but shell expansion of `~` won't work.  Also launchd won't allow your shell command to create a dynamic file name. You're better off wrapping all of this in a shell script and calling it from launchd instead.

In order to run this script only while MySQL is running you could use the `KeepAlive` key like this:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
    <key>PathState</key>
    <dict>
        <key>/var/run/mysql.pid</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This approach assumes that your MySQL instance writes its current PID to the file `/var/run/mysql.pid`. The file will only be there while MySQL is running.

As you correctly pointed out `StartInterval` and `KeepAlive` don't work together. The script would be fired regardless of the existence of the PID file. The correct approach is to use `ThrottleInterval` instead of `StartInterval`. This key determines how much time has to pass between starts. Use it like this:

```
<ThrottleInterval>
<integer>120</integer>
```

Have a look at `launchd.plist(5)`. It explains all the options in great detail.

Comment: In order to do that would I simply put the long command into a shell script (presumably with a `#!/bin/bash` first line)? Then just call the shell script?

Comment: Right, I've worked that out. The answer to my question is yes. The only other thing that's now going to cause an issue is that I want it to run only when MAMP/MySQL is running. Is that possible?

Comment: Or rather, as a quicker solution, how do I redirect the output of errors to stop it generating internal mail?

Comment: I see you've been asking a related question about redirecting the output of errors. Why not do it properly and use the `KeepAlive` key as suggested above? This way the backup will only be performed while MySQL is up.

Comment: Having read countless threads all over the place, I found [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10655138#10655138) that suggests it is not possible to have both `KeepAlive` and `StartInterval` together. If that is incorrect then my appologies, but I figured the new approach was a better idea (anyone looking for that, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332276/send-stderr-to-dev-null-but-if-no-error-occurs-continue-on/)). Nonetheless, your answer is correct, so I will mark it as such.

Comment: You are right. I've extended my answer to address this problem.